# Why does the delay between bytes increase when I increase UART baud rate?

Tags: c, serial-port, embedded, avr, uart

Something interesting to note, which I am not fully understanding. My UART is initialized with 9600 baud. I've looked at the TX on the line via logic analyzer, and the bytes I send have minimal delay. It is 36µs per byte, which is expected.

Now, if I initialize that UART with a different baud rate, say 115,200, the delay between each byte sent increases significantly. It jumps to 125µs per byte.

This is causing a problem, since I've got to increase my baud rate at some point, but have a time constraint on my response.

Shouldn't the delay ***decrease*** between bytes, since it should be sending more bits at the same frequency?

This blocking method is for writing to the UART.

```
static inline void uart2_putchar(uint8_t data)
{
    // Disable interrupts to get exclusive access to ring_buffer_out.
    cli();
    if (ring_buffer_is_empty(&ring_buffer_out2)) {
        // First data in buffer, enable data ready interrupt
        UCSR2B |=  (1 << UDRIE2);
    }
    // Put data in buffer
    ring_buffer_put(&ring_buffer_out2, data);

    // Re-enable interrupts
    sei();
}
```

Which is triggered based on an interrupt.

```
ISR(USART2_UDRE_vect)
{
    // if there is data in the ring buffer, fetch it and send it
    if (!ring_buffer_is_empty(&ring_buffer_out2)) {
        UDR2 = ring_buffer_get(&ring_buffer_out2);
    }
    else {
        // no more data to send, turn off data ready interrupt
        UCSR2B &= ~(1 << UDRIE2);
    }
}
```

Timing Diagrams below:

~9600 Baud Rate -- 
[image]
[image]

~115,200 Baud Rate --
[image]

Comment: It sounds like your problem has to do with handshaking delays and/or the ability for your program to provide data as fast as the pipe can handle it.

Comment: This is using an ATMega2560, and I am writing to the hardware UART on the device. There shouldn't be any handshaking issue. What doesn't make sense is why the delay increases as the baud rate increases, and vice versa. I thought it was supposed to be the other way around.

Comment: The folks over at http://electronics.stackexchange.com are probably in a better position to answer your question, unless you can show us the code you are using.  Your code may be waiting on the UART to signal that it is ready, or there may be a blocking method call somewhere.

Comment: In any case, 125 microseconds corresponds to about 8K bytes per second (about 80K bits per second, give or take a parity bit), so you should already be pretty close to maximum theoretical throughput.

Comment: The only blocking item in my code is when the UART needs to transmit data from the ring buffer. It is used to ensure no one is able to interrupt it to secure data integrity. Code posted as an edit.

Comment: How radical of a context change is the CLI and SEI?  Could that be causing the delay?  Is the ring buffer an efficient one?  You might need to insert some timer code to see where the delay is occurring.

Comment: *"Shouldn't the delay decrease between bytes..."* No, the baud rate only affects the bit timing within the data frame.  This is an **asynchronous** link, so there are no timing specifications on the interval between frames.  The longer delays could be explained by interrupt latency.  How prevalent is the use of CLI in your code?  Your `putchar()` introduces a lot of overhead for outputting strings.

Comment: sawdust -- CLI is called only in the ISR, shown above, for transmitting data.

RobertHarvey -- The ring buffer is the one provided by amtel, I haven't changed their library.

Comment: @sawdust since I am using the ring_buffer library that amtel provides, what would be a better alternative for transmitting strings/buffers that are 20-30 bytes long?

Comment: Sigh, the problem was reading the scales incorrectly. To address my other issue that relates to this problem is something else. The device is working as intended.

Comment: *"CLI is called only in the ISR"* -- I don't see any CLI in the ISR, but it's in the baselevel `uart2_putchar()` routine.  Overuse or frequent use of CLI in baselevel code will increase interrupt latencies and ruin responsiveness of a system.  Your `uart*_putchar()` introduces a lot of overhead for outputting strings.  Is there a (more efficient) `putstring()` that does not invoke `putchar()`, but can copy the string into the ring buffer in one or two moves?. Another approach is "list (or stack) of buffers".

Comment: You could make a test with `ISR(USART2_UDRE_vect) { UDR2 = 0x81; }` and avoid to use cli/sei while testing. You should measure minimal delays.

Comment: so you are using an interrupt not polling?  Have you tried a polling loop that just transmits as fast as it can rather than this ring stuff?  Basically divide the problem in half, and then half again, etc.  Does the problem have anything at all to do with the uart?  Is it strictly based on the amount of code?  Is it based on interrupt overhead?  Is it something specific in your code?  Etc.

Comment: Is there no interrupt flag you should be clearing, rather than setting the interrupt enable? Or is this done automatically when the interrupt is triggered? How do you check errors such as framing, overrun etc? Are they too handled by the same interrupt, or a different one?

Comment: How quickly are you calling `uart2_putchar`? It seems logical that you will wait more between characters, given faster baud rate and same buffer fill speed. Also, the code seems like it may have a race condition; it's not the best idea to write to an address from both the interrupt and user code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three points to check:

- Do you feed the buffer fast enough? If not, the increased gap is due to your data providing code, not due to an internal behaviour of the processor. (use a toggle pin to find out)
- Is it possible that because of the increased speed, your code just switches off the data register empty interrupt every single time it transmits data? 
  Instead of using a put_char to fill up your ringbuffer, you could use a put_string(array, length) to fill it up with multiple chars at once (using memcopy for example, think about splitting it up into two mwmcopy operations when data has to wrap at the end of the buffer).
  (again, use a toggle pin to find out).
- Reduce the code wraped into cli() and sei() to a minimum. Switch filling up the buffer with the flag check and and exclude this part from the cli-sei part

good luck!

Comment: The interrupts were too much for the processor to handle. I switched to polling and there is almost no delay in all transactions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you call uart2_putchar() often enough, your circular buffer is never empty and the the gap you measure is determined by the interrupt response time.

However, when you increase the baudrate you'll empty that buffer a lot quicker.  Up to a critical point where the interrupt handler will find the buffer empty and cannot transmit a byte.  The gap you measure is now determined by the rate at which you call uart2_putchar().